# Ignoring soft foreign keys when referenced row no longer exists

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, foreign-keys, nhibernate-mapping

I’m presently working with a NHibernate application that contains table *A* that once had a foreign key reference to another related table *B*. This constraint has since been purposely removed as items in *B* may be deleted out of my control by a secondary application.

Though the constraint is now gone the reference from *A* to *B* can still be considered useful if the row in *B* still exists, otherwise it may be treated a null.

If a row is deleted from *B* that is referenced by *A*, quite rightly, an exception is thrown stating that "No row with the given identifier exists".

Is there a way to fluently (or otherwise avoiding explicit queries/joins) to have the object reference return null by the application in the case of a reference from *A* no longer existing in *B*, but returning the object as described by *B* if the reference is valid?

The current unidirectional fluent mapping (treated as a foreign key reference) is rather straight forward looking like

```
...
References(a => a.b_ref, "b_id");
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reference can be ignored and treated as null when not found by updating the fluent mapping to look like

```
...
References(a => a.b_ref, "b_id").NotFound.Ignore();
...
```

Sometimes it's just a matter of stumbling into the right keyword via Google.